# SQL Insert Select when select retrieves multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Tables:

workstation

- id
- name
- user_id

user

- id
- name

My business requirement is: I want two new workstations, named "A" and "B" for each user that still don't have any workstation (don't have an entry in the workstation table).

So, it's like a for each.

For each user that I found in the select I want to do two inserts (for 'A' and 'B'), like

```
insert into workstation(name, user_id) 
values('A', select id from user where id not in (select user_id from workstation));
```

This doesn't work because the 'A' is hardcoded and the select retrieves multiple id's. And even if it worked for 'A', will fail for 'B' for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple records from select statement directly as following

```
insert into workstation(name, user_id) 
select 'A', id from user where id not in (select user_id from workstation)
union
select 'B', id from user where id not in (select user_id from workstation);
```

to add them to `'A'` and `'B'` in same time union both select in same statement to ensure you add them for `'A'` and `'B'` workstation

for more details you can check insert in postgre [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-insert.html)

Comment: I like this, but it wont work. If the user ID is in the workstation table under a different workstation i.e. workstation "C" - no inserts will occur as the user ID still exists.

Comment: For my use case it works because I want to add only if it doesn't exist at all. So this works for workstation A. Thank you for the help, Ahmed Yousif. What doesn't work her but I'm not sure if it is possible is that I'd like to add the workstation 'A' but also 'B'. if I run this twice the second insert will not work because the select will retrieve no records, since we just added the workstation A for those users. Any possibility to add for 'A', but also for 'B'?

Comment: @JoãoCorreia please,check updated solution I believe to will do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is more accurate for you.

```
insert into workstation(name, user_id) 
select 'A', id from user where (select count(*) from workstation where name = 'A' and user_id = user.id) = 0
union
select 'B', id from user where (select count(*) from workstation where name = 'B' and user_id = user.id) = 0
```

Comment: I tried your answer and worked perfectly also, I just needed to add the  "where" instead of the first "and". Thank you very much, you guys helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

select id from user where id not in (select user_id from workstation) may return multiple records and i guess this is where it fails. Have you tried limiting the extracted records to only single records? 
Syntax might not be correct:

```
insert into workstation(name, user_id) values('A', (select id from user where id not in (select user_id from workstation) Limit 1))
```

This will get only one record that is not already present in the Workstation table even if there are multiple records for which are not already there in the workstation table.

Answer (score 0):

insert into workstation ( name, user_id)

```
with ws as (select 'A' name from dual 
            union all 
            select 'B" from dual
           )
select ws.name, user_id
  from ws, users u
where not exists 
      (select null 
         from workstation w
        where w.user_id = u.user_id 
      ) ;
```

Note: user is a reserved word and should not be used as a table name.